# how to call server app servlet from android app to register device when implementing GCM

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to understand GCM from the developer android site. I have implemented the client side android app following the instructions at http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html and the http server app(NOT the XMPP based server app) following the instructions at http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html. The code i used is downloaded from https://code.google.com/p/gcm/ as they have mentioned. The GCM registration function works perfectly on my phone.

**Now the problem is, how do i send the registration id of my phone to my http server app.** I know that i should be placing some code in sendRegistrationIdToBackend() in the DemoActivity.java file of the android app to simply call the RegisterServlet on my server app. But i am new to java and android, and just cannot figure out how to do that. Any advice on how i can go about writing this code would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a sample code for sending the registration ID to your server using an HTTP GET request. I'm using classes of the `org.apache.http.*` library. It assumes you have a page on your server that accepts the registration ID in a parameter called regId (in the sample it's a `jsp` page, but it can be `PHP` of whatever you have in your server). You'll have to add error handling code and parsing of the server response in order to complete this sample.

```
  String responseString= null;

  try {
    URI url            = new URI ("http://your-server-domain/your-server-page.jsp?regId="+THE_REGISTRATION_ID);
    HttpGet httpGet    = new HttpGet (url);
    // defaultHttpClient
    HttpParams
      httpParameters   = new BasicHttpParams();

    // Set the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is established.
    // The default value is zero, that means the timeout is not used. 
    int
      timeoutConnection= 3000;
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout (
      httpParameters,
      timeoutConnection
                         );

    // Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT) 
    // in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
    int timeoutSocket  = 5000;
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout (
      httpParameters,
      timeoutSocket
                         );

    DefaultHttpClient
     httpClient        = new DefaultHttpClient (httpParameters);

    HttpResponse
      httpResponse     = httpClient.execute (httpGet);
    HttpEntity
      httpEntity       = httpResponse.getEntity ();

    if (httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200)
    {
      Log.e (
        _context.getString(R.string.app_name),
        "Server Call Failed : Got Status Code " + httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() + " and ContentType " + httpEntity.getContentType().getValue()
                         );
      // add code to handle error
    }

    responseString     = EntityUtils.toString (httpEntity);
  } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    Log.e(_context.getString(R.string.app_name),e.toString(),e);
    // add code to handle error
  } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    Log.e(_context.getString(R.string.app_name),e.toString(),e);
    // add code to handle error
  } catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(_context.getString(R.string.app_name),e.toString(),e);
    // add code to handle error
  } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    Log.e(_context.getString(R.string.app_name),e.toString(),e);
    // add code to handle error
  }
```

Comment: That worked! Since i am using a servlet on the web server to process the registration request i use `URI url            = new URI ("http://server-domain/register?regId="+THE_REGISTRATION_ID);` in the HTTP GET request. And made sure that i have the entry   `<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RegisterServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/register</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>` in my server app's web.xml file.

Comment: How did you implement your http server so that it accepts a registration ID?

Comment: @user2320244 That's too long to answer here. You should first choose the language you wish to implement your server in (Java Servlet,JSP,PHP,.NET, etc...)

Comment: I've planned to use Java Servlet.