# Setting up Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) HTTP server and client

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Most of the solutions listed on web use GCMRegistrar which has been deprecated. I downloaded the source for client and server from https://code.google.com/p/gcm/ and followed guide as mentioned on https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html and client.html Substituting SENDER_ID on client and api.key on server. Then transferred client and server to same local network with internet access and removed IP restriction in Google APIs Console. When I run client it shows me Device registered, registration ID successful. But the problem is server(Tomcat) shows "No devices registered!"

Comment: Have you stored the registration id for the device/project on your server and are you sending this to the Google server along with your message?

Comment: I'm assuming from your description that your client fails to connect to your server in order to send it the registration ID it received from Google (or that you don't have the client code that does this sending).

Comment: @NickT No I'm not. But according to demo server documentation you can send the message to devices.

Comment: @Eran Since I'm not providing information about my server anywhere on the client. The GCM server handles the push message from my server.

Comment: @2600th But how do you transfer the registration ID from the client to your server? If you don't do that, it's not surprise that your server shows "No devices registered".

Comment: @2600th The registration I'd is the 'address' of the device/project combination. It has to be attached to the message, otherwise it can't be delivered. Your server needs to know it.

Comment: @NickT Yeah that was the problem. I added my device Id to regIds on server and then sent a message. It worked Thanks. But the demo project provided by google doesn't contain any implementation of the same. I found an empty method sendRegistrationIdToBackend() in DemoActivity. Should I open a direct connection to the server and send the IDs or there is some other way.

Comment: @Eran Thanks I solved it as described above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send device ids to server in order to create a notification. The gcm demo doesn't implement this functionality. Thanks to @Eran [how to call server app servlet from android app to register device when implementing GCM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551266/how-to-call-server-app-servlet-from-android-app-to-register-device-when-implemen)