# Android Google Cloud Messaging - can't complete

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I looked over several tutorials and still can't complete this part in my app.
Sorry, I'm quite new so don't downvote me please.

I got everything right in my manifest, in MainActivity I have

```
public void registerService(){

    Intent registrationIntent=new Intent ("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");
    registrationIntent.putExtra("app",PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext,0, new Intent(), 0));
    registrationIntent.putExtra("sender", stringWithSenderID);
    startService(registrationIntent);
}
```

GCMReceiver :

```
public class GCMReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        try{
            String action=intent.getAction();
            if (action.equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION")){
                String registrationid=intent.getStringExtra("registration_id");
                Log.d("MyLog","registrationid ="+registrationid);
                String error=   intent.getStringExtra("error");
                String unregistered=intent.getStringExtra("unregistered");

            }
            else if (action.equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE")){
                String data1=intent.getStringExtra("data1");
                String data2=intent.getStringExtra("data2");

            }
        } finally{

        }

    }

}
```

So I got my registration_id Logged right, what do I do next? Do I have to send it to server somehow?

Comment: yes, to your server, from there you will send cloud commands.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to call server app servlet from android app to register device when implementing GCM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551266/how-to-call-server-app-servlet-from-android-app-to-register-device-when-implemen)

Answer (score 0):

I think it helps you:

```
public String Sender_id = "your_google_api_sender_id";
try {
            GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
            GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
            String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);

            if (regId.equals("")) {
                GCMRegistrar.register(this, Sender_id);
            } else {
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

And in GCm Srevice we have to write like this:

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {



    @Override
    protected void onError(Context context, String error) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (error != null) {
            // optionally retry using exponential back-off
            // (see Advanced Topics)
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "" + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }

    }

    public GCMIntentService() {
        super("your_snde_id");
        // SENDER_ID is my project id into google account url
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public GCMIntentService(String senderId) {
        super(senderId);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //createNotification(context, message);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context context, String regId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // you need to handle what you have to do after registration

    }

    @Override
    protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String error) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }





}
```

and In Manifest file like this:

```
    <permission
        android:name="your.package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="your.package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <!-- App receives GCM messages. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.UNREGISTER" />

                <category android:name="com.activelifeapps.android.alAlleghany" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="your.package.GCMIntentService" />
```

Comment: The method createNotification(Context, String) is undefined for the type GCMIntentService

Comment: ok.. so .. how do I make this message as push notification? how can I make such message that goes with other push-notifications I get?

Comment: And aLSO, HERE is no implementation of  onRegistered(Context context, String regId) - How  do I send regID to server?

Comment: you have to store registrationid in your server, with that refference your server has to send notifications

Comment: yeah you can make your notifications with the messages